# Как правильно сгенерировать ссылку для восстановления пароля?

Tags: безопасность, php, отправка, шифрование, восстановление

Здравствуйте!

Пишу скрипт восстановления пароля для сайта.

Принцип работы следующий:

1. Пользователь вводит email
2. Получает письмо
3. Проходит по ссылке
4. Вводит новый пароль

Но я не знаю как защитить ссылку, которую отсылаю на email и что вообще можно и нужно в ней передать!!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

**Пока додумался до такого варианта:**

Получаю Email, проверяю есть ли он в базе.
Затем логин, пароль, email беру в одну строку, кодирую в md5().

```
$str = md5($login.$pass,$email);
```

Отправляю письмо со ссылкой: www.сайт.ru?getPass=$str

Далее я так понимаю, нужно создать базу данных, чтобы туда поместить $str, ведь когда я её получу ?getPass=$str , мне надо будет её сравнить...

Ну а в таблице соответственно указать дату, чтобы например через сутки удалить, если пользователь не перешел по ссылке.

Ну вот, я бы сделал так, но мне хотелось бы чтобы более опытные программисты подсказали как лучше

Comment: Код-ревью провели )) можно так сделать.
$str можешь вообще случайным образом генерить и хранить в базе.

Comment: Добавьте к `$login.$pass` ещё кодовую фразу по типу
`$login.$pass.'my supersecret textjlkfMUIY&*^FWf8&(*fhw9f)'.getmicrotime()` - это спасет от умников, которые будут подделывать ваши ссылки. Время нужно, дабы ссылки для юзера были всегда разные.
Читал какось про взлом сайта через восстановление пароля. Там ссылка генерилась через random(). Хакер расчитывал вероятные ответы random() в зависимости от времени суток и подделывал ссылки восстановления пароля.

Answer (score 4):

Да, Вы правы, $str можно сгенерировать случайным образом, я в общем сделал следующее: закодировал строку в md5()? создал базу данных в которую поместил это значение, и когда пользователь проходит по закодированной ссылке, я сверяю её с базой данных, и если есть совпадения, выдаю форму для заполнения нового пароля!!!

Comment: На самом деле - это единственный способ, который более-менее гарантирует безопасность.

Answer (score 3):

А я бы создал отдельную табличку или дополнительные записи.

Например табличка `Pass_recovery` с полями `user_id, access_hash, expires`.

`user_id` - `id` юзверя (внешний ключ)

`access_hash` - произвольный `md5()` или `sha1()` хэш доступа, любой, пусть даже `md5(time())`

`expires` - например 1 час с момента запроса на восстановление пароля

Потом на email слать ссылку типа:

```
www.site.com?=recovery_id=$user_id&recovery_hash=$access_hash
```

Скриптом по `recovery_id` мы быстро находим из таблицы `Pass_recovery` значения и сверяем  `recovery_id == user_id` и `recovery_hash == access_hash`.

Быстро, так как это по идее должен быть индекс в таблице! 
Если проверка успешная то предлагаем юзверю ввести пароль прямо на сайте.
После этого очистить accessHash в таблице.

Comment: я тоже примерно так делаю!

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = dechex(time()).md5(uniqid($email));
```

`md5(uniqid($email))` - защита от подбора
`dechex(time())` - защита от коллизий хешей

Для дополнительной защиты в базу также сохранять и при проверке ссылки сверять IP адрес клиента и возможно User Agent браузера.

Comment: допзащита эта не пойдет, а если я запросил восстановление пароля с мобильника, будучи подключенным по 3g, а потом пришел домой и увидел, что письмо пришло, то я уже с домашнего компа не смогу активировать... либо банальная смена IP после переподключения... не, ИМХО, плохая затея.

Comment: А я обычно вставляю беспалевно в хеш юзер айди шифрованный. И таймаут минуток на 15.